# CSS nesting declarations

Tags: css, nested

https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-nesting/

What is the status of nesting styles?

Is there any support so far, or the near future?

I think that variables and nesting are the only things needed by css to avoid css pre processors. And variables are working

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting-1/ March 2019

Comment: you will probably have something in 2 years

Answer (score 0):

CSS Nesting is an early stage draft of the CSSWG.

It has been [merged](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/pull/2878) into the [csswg-drafts repository](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/tree/master/css-nesting-1) in March 2019. According to [cssdb](https://cssdb.org/#nesting-rules) which classifies it as [stage 1](https://cssdb.org/#stage-1), there are currently no browsers implementing CSS Nesting. But you can use a [PostCSS plugin](https://github.com/jonathantneal/postcss-nesting). As it is an *early* draft, it may be changed or rejected.